# How can I run ANT from a batch file without having an Environment Variable set?

Tags: ant, build, compc

I want to include ANT, the JavaSDK and FlexSDK into my project directory.  I need people in my company to be able to compile from source code.

I have a build.bat file which starts with :

```
ant blah/blah/blah
```

But what if I want to run ANT directly without the system environment variable? If I remove these from the system `ant is not recognised`.

I am a real newbie here, but I want to do something like this:

```
start "${basedir}\libs\ant\bin" ant -lib ${basedir}/libs/ant/lib/flexTasks.jar
pause
```

This is so that other people dont need to install a whole load of software... IT would all be contained in the folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set those environment variables in the same batchfile, i.e. something like :

```
set ANT_HOME=C:\ant182
set ANT_ARGS=-lib C:\antxtralibs
set JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk160_30
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin

:: default
ant -f %1

:: debug
:: ant -debug -f %1
```