# How to deploy a portlet to Liferay from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I've made a portlet in Eclipse and now I'd like to deploy it to a running Liferay-6.1 instance and debug it. I guess this should be described in documentation, but I was only able to found how to create the portlet, but not how to deploy it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a screenshot which shows how-to deploy Liferay portlet directly from Eclipse

[image]

Comment: For clarification, you need to right-click on the project name for this menu.  It took me a while to realize this when I couldn't find these options from the main menu - but this screenshot led me to it.

Answer (score 2):

How to deploy a portlet in Eclipse (using Liferay IDE) is [documented here.](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/deploying-new-liferay-projects-to-liferay-serv-4)  This assumes that you have [installed Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/installati-6), then [created a Liferay Server adapter](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/set-ndash-4), and then [created a project](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-new-liferay-projec-4) using New Liferay Project wizard.

Answer (score 1):

After completion of developing the portlet go to the browser open the localhost sign in and then-->Goto Add--->more-->expand the sample--->Select Add
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy it by using command prompt. Go to location of your plugin portlet and execute the following command:

eg:

```
D:\Projects\plugin\portlets\test-portlet>ant deploy
```

Note: you need to configure ant home like [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290243/how-to-set-ant-home-with-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a plugin project, but you need to deploy it onto your Liferay Server. Let’s do it now:

Select your new plugin project then right click the Liferay Server in the Servers tab;

Select Add and Remove….

Select your plugin project and click Add to deploy it to the server.

Click Finish.

You should see the project get deployed to Liferay Tomcat server; in the console you’ll see a message indicating your new portlet is available for use.