# GWT-showcase and ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, gwt, uibinder

HOW DO I INCLUDE GWT-SHOWCASE IN ECLIPSE-JUNO?
my eclipse version is not showing "New –> Other –> Google –> Web Application Project" option also?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to work with gwt sources (including the showcase example), is to follow the instructions in the '[Working with the code](http://www.gwtproject.org/makinggwtbetter.html#workingoncode)' section of the gwt documentation.

Basically checkout the code and the necessary tools:

```
 $ git clone https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt trunk
 $ svn checkout http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tools/ tools
```

Then setup eclipse and import the projects you want to work with following the steps  explained in the [README.txt](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/eclipse/README.txt) into the `trunk/eclipse` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Run from the command line (in project SHOWCASE directory):

```
ant eclipse.generate
```

If you want ant in system environment variable see -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290431/904820

And then you can import project to eclipse.